# Setting properties of ArcGIS Server services over command line?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I would like to set the pooling property of 100 ArcGIS 10.3.1 map services. This task takes about 2 minutes for each service if I use ArcGIS Server Manager because it restarts the service automatically.

Is there a command line method to do this for all services?

Comment: Command-line, no, but there are examples using JavaScript and Python in the documentation (tracing the Manager request is a good starting point). There's no getting around bouncing the service when changing service properties. Note that inexpertly changing all services to zero default servers can significantly  ***increase*** system load.

Comment: FWIW, you should also stagger the service restart times while you're iterating your service properties.